# Navigationview menu is not closing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, post, navigation-drawer

am coding some android website interpreter,the ui is some kind of drowerlayout with navigation menu and when click some item a POST function is executed and this can take some times 10 seconds 
so i have a layout with waiting imageview that i wan to show until getin responce

the activity_main:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
...>
<RelativeLayout
           ...>
    <my.package.ui.InteractiveScrollView
                                    ...>
        <LinearLayout
                  ...>
    <include layout="@layout/result_layout" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </my.package.ui.InteractiveScrollView>
    <include layout="@layout/waiting_layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
...>
</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
...        

final NavigationView nav_view = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            dl.closeDrawers();
            waiting_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            int id = menuItem.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.ITEM1) {
                functionPOST();
                waiting_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

dl.closeDrawers is not working and the menu is not closing ,the waiting layout is not showing i cant figure if just the menu is hiding it or its not showing
and the application is blocking until post request get return
the post request is running as AsyncTask

any solution or explanation i will be grateful

Comment: Set a breakpoint at closeDrawers and see if the function is being called.

Comment: its being called,but how be sure is being executed?